# How to set the frame for opening pdf in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, pdf-tools

I have two links in my org buffer:

```
[file://tmp/foo.pdf]
[file://tmp/bar.pdf]
```

Hitting enter on `[file://tmp/foo.pdf]` opens the pdf in the same frame (using pdf-tools / ..Running /usr/bin/xdg-open..).

I split the frames in order to see the pdf alongside the org buffer.

But now hitting enter on `[file://tmp/bar.pdf]` opens again in the same frame, and now I don't see my org buffer anymore, have to switch it again etc.

How can I open the file in org but use the other frame for it's displaying?

`Ctrl h v org-link-frame-setup` returns

```
org-link-frame-setup is a variable defined in ‘ol.el’.
Its value is
((vm . vm-visit-folder-other-frame)
 (vm-imap . vm-visit-imap-folder-other-frame)
 (gnus . org-gnus-no-new-news)
 (file . find-file-other-window)
 (wl . wl-other-frame))
```

I tried `(file . find-file-other-frame)` without effect

Comment: What's the value of `org-link-frame-setup` in your configuration?

Comment: Is that excerpt you added in a `(customize-set-variables ....)`?

Comment: It might be clearer if you did `C-h v org-link-frame-setup RET`: that would tell you what the actual value of the variable is. After all, there might be a bug in your init.el, so the code in your excerpt might not be evalueted and the variable might not be set properly.